# How to pass more than one record between two forms?

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, args, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I want to pass more than one record between two forms. The user opens Form-A, selects multiple records and then clicks a button that opens Form-B.
In Form-B there are two (or more) `StringEdit` controls and they should display values from the selected records.

I know how to pass only one record, to do that I use the following code in a method of Form-B:

```
if (element.args().parmEnumType() == enumNum(NoYes) 
 && element.args().parmEnum() == NoYes::Yes)
{
    myTable = element.args().record();
    stringEdit.text(myTable.Field);
}
```

How should I change my code so that I can set the text of another `StringEdit` control to the field value of the next record that the user selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you can use an `args` to pass the records, which you will need to prepare in your Form-A, as below (taking the SalesTable as example);

```
int         recordsCount;
SalesTable  salesTable;
container   con;
Args        args = newArgs();

// gets the total records selected
recordsCount = salesTable_ds.recordsMarked().lastIndex();
salesTable = salesTable_ds.getFirst(1);
while(salesTable)
{
    // storing recid of selected record in container
    con = conIns(con,1, salesTable.RecId);
    salesTable = SampleTable_ds.getNext(); // moves to next record
}   
// passing container converted to string 
args.parm(con2Str(con,','));
```

Then on your Form-B, you will need to override the `init()` method to read the args you created,

In order to retrieve passed arguments in the recipient from. Override the init() method of new form as shown

```
public void init()
{
    container   con;
    int         i;
    super();       
    // string to container
    con = str2con(element.args().parm(),'','');    
    // for sorting
    for(i = 1;i<= conLen(con) ;i++)
    {
        salesTable_ds.query().dataSourceTable(Tablenum(SalesTable)).addRange(fieldNum(SalesTable,RecId)).value(SysQuery::value(conPeek(con,i)));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Taken from [Ax-Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsaxbitsandbytesfromsyed/archive/2014/05/18/pass-multiple-records-from-one-form-to-another.aspx)

Comment: Thanks fr your help Nadeem_MK,

Comment: Thanks fr your help Nadeem_MK,
whith your code i give more records from first from(A)
but i have in both dataSource Form my SalesTable?
I have a easy question, where i have to fill my stringEdit in second form(B)?
I need to pute code look like in secondform(B):
     stringEdit.text(SalesTable.field);

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the question properly but if you need to set the data / manipulate the record, you will need to put it in the loop itself. Between `for(i = 1;i<= conLen(con) ;i++)
    {`

Answer (score 3):

This will typically imply looping through the selected records in `Form-A` and changing the query in `Form-B`.

The idiomatic way to loop through selected records involves a `for` loop and the `getFirst` and `getNext` methods of the datasource:

```
SalesLine sl;
FormDataSourcs ds = _salesLine.dataSource();
for (sl = ds.getFirst(true) ? ds.getFirst(true) : ds.cursor(); sl; sl = ds.getNext())
{       
    //Do your thing, add a query range
}
```

The [MultiSelectionHelper](http://dynamicsnavax.blogspot.dk/2010/04/ax-multiselectionhelper.html) class may be of use here, as it does the thing:

```
public void init()
{
    MultiSelectionHelper ms;
    super();       
    if (element.args() && element.args().caller() && element.args().record())
    {
        this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesLine)).clearDynalinks();
        ms = MultiSelectionHelper::createFromCaller(element.args().caller());        
        ms.createQueryRanges(this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(SalesLine)), fieldstr(SalesLine, InventTransId));
    }
}
```

Comment: A better example using MultiSelectionHelper